# Positioning divs next to each other

Tags: html, css, position

I always struggle a bit when it comes to positioning divs. This is what I would like to have, fitting the whole page, without any margin or padding:

```
 ____  __  __
|    ||__||__|
|____||__||__|
 ____________
|____________|
```

With the drawing above in mind, this is what I want to accomplish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE9Ad.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want something like this:

```
<div class="horizontal_container">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
<div></div>
```

with the associated style:

```
div.horizontal_container div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

By default, `div`s are block level elements, but the `inline-block` display style will allow the three inner divs to appear next to each other.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've attached an image in my original post, this will clearify a bit.